# Clicking on a articles category module title redirect to another page. How to avoid this?

Tags: joomla-3.x, module, articles, permissions

my question is really simple:

I have a Joomla website with a private part, and different categories of articles. I have a main "news" page, with the public articles displayed there. I have a private "news" page (built using the "articles category" module), with only articles from the private category, only accessible by registered users.

The problem I have is: when a registered user click on a private "news" title or the "read more" button, the complete article is open as if it was opened from the main "news" page (the same url, loaded modules, etc), so it's "outside the private zone" of the website. How can I change this behavior? Modifying the "articles category" module and adding the Itemid=xxx to the created links, so the article is opened inside the private zone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, what you need to do is create a top level page for your private news blog - an actual menu item for category blog. Then you can control what modules and url those articles get when clicked on, and keep it's users restricted to private.

Comment: Yes, you understood my problem correctly! I'm sorry, but I can't upvote your answer, I haven't enough reputation... :/

Comment: No worries, just glad you got things running.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to this is to use NoNumber's Advanced Module Manager to load the modules JUST for a certain category, user ACL level or any number of criteria. If you just need this one fix, then I'd use REactionFaye's option, but if you need to do this for other sections, AMM is very handy.

http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/advancedmodulemanager